# How to bring and save data between firebase and unity using C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I'm setting up a unity project with firebase and want to write code in C# to bring data from firebase and save data to firebase and make login page..etc
I see all functions but I need a whole way from beginning to end

Answer (score 0):

First you need to setup the whole project. This tutorial is from the official Firebase guide:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup

And more information for the first steps you can find under:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/start

Here you can find all the information you need like how to structure your data, save it and retrieve it.

Basically I would recommend you to start with this, working and playing around with it and if you have problems or questions you can come back and ask for help.

Comment: Sorry that i can't provide you more information, but StackOverflow is not a platform for giving complete tutorials over specific topics.